# JS как уменьшить размер изображения перед загрузкой на сервер?

Tags: javascript

Нужно распознавать `qr` коды. Что-то типа сканера `qr` кодов.
Хочу загружать на сервер фото qr кодов для распознавания на сервере. НО камера делает фотку в довольно большом разрешении, хотя надобности в этом нет, фотка по 1-2 мб.
Вот я и думаю перед отправкой на сервер - сжать, обрезать, уменьшить изображение и отправить уже килобайт 100 максимум, а то и 50.

Скажите - можно ли это сделать на мобильном браузере средствами `JS`?
Может, можно средствами `js` распознать код? Было бы вообще круто.

PS. Я понимаю, что лучше сделать мобильное приложение, которое распознает, но это дороже и трудозатратнее. Интересует именно момент решения этой задачи браузером пока что. Потом возможно сделаем приложение.

Comment: https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR